# query to get records by multiple ranges in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3, cassandra-2.0

I have following model:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS log (
  date varchar,
  timeid timeuuid,
  message varchar,
  ip varchar,
  time timestamp,
  user bigint,
  file varchar,
  line int,
  func varchar,
  level int,
  PRIMARY KEY (date, timeid, time)
) WITH CLUSTERING order by (timeid DESC);
```

How I can get all logs of some day, where record is between given timeid and time values?

Currently problem is because if I use timeid>something, I cannot use time>something, because cassandra doesn't allow multiple filtering (non-EQ) on clustering keys.

I tried something like

```
SELECT * FROM log 
    WHERE date='2014-09-14' 
    AND (timeid, time) <= (1245a230-3baa-11e4-8ca7-4bdg1fe06d46, '2014-09-14 03:57:16+0200') 
    AND (timeid, time) >= (cb66eef0-3ba9-11e4-8ca7-4bd6sfe06d46, '2015-09-14 02:57:14+0200');
```

but in this case cassandra is not restricting time, so still I will get values even before 2015-09-14 02:57:14+0200, so it is just looking for timeid value.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

TimeUUID's have the timestamp encoded in them, so unless the timestamp you are using in your timeuuid is different than the time value, you should be ok just filtering based on timeid.

Not only that, but cql has some builtin functions to make this easier for example

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
   WHERE t > maxTimeuuid('2013-01-01 00:05+0000')
   AND t < minTimeuuid('2013-02-02 10:00+0000')
```

Reference [Datastax Documentation on TimeUUID functions](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/timeuuid_functions_r.html)

Comment: problem i because I can have many records on '2013-01-01 00:05+0000', and I need somehow know which are newer and which are older.With this '2013-01-01 00:05+0000' I get precision only in seconds, which is not so good in my case. Any other idea?

Comment: Timeuuids support timestamps with a very high precision,
timeuuid
Uses the time in 100 nanosecond intervals since 00:00:00.00 UTC (60 bits), a clock sequence number for prevention of duplicates (14 bits), plus the IEEE 801 MAC address (48 bits) to generate a unique identifier. For example: d2177dd0-eaa2-11de-a572-001b779c76e3